# Проблема с удалением div

Tags: javascript

Есть разметка, я ее добавляю в `js`, с помощью `insertAdjacentHTML`

```
<a class="button_green" href="${array_for_href[i]}" target="_blank">
  <span class="action_button_left"></span>
  <span class="action_button_contents">${name_market[i]}</span>
  <span class="action_button_right"></span>
  <span class="action_button_preload"></span>
</a>
```

Когда выбирается другой предмет, то кнопка от прошлого предмета удаляется и кнопка нового добавляется.

```
function delete_for_button_green() {
  var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("button_green");
  if (elem.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
      elem[i].remove();
    }
  }
}
```

Мой `div` с классом `button_green` после после например 10 раз просмотра предметов остается в DOM. Так как тут моему `div` с классом `button_green` присваивается пустая строка, а сам `div` остается. Когда я меняю строчку `elem[i].innerHTML = '';` на `elem[i].remove();` то скрип когда выбираешь любой третий предмет, остаются две кнопки. Почему это происходит и как можно избежать? Или совет как удалить мой `div` с классом `button_green`полностью?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` возвращает "обновляющуюся" коллекцию:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

```
    for(var i = elem.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        elem[i].remove();
    }
```